# Is it possible to get logged admin email in Strapi?

Tags: strapi

can i get SuperAdmin email from my api?
I mean this email:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the strapi plugin

```
  await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.user.find();
```

instead of

```
await strapi.query("strapi::user").find({})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i found.

```
await strapi.query("strapi::user").find({})
```